# office365 microsoft graph group conversation

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am newbie in graph API. I am trying to access the Group Conversation using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/id/conversations?. but result shows 
"The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it". all groups having Conversation 
is that any other way to access group conversation..?

Comment: Did you check this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3006861 - There is a KB entry and a software update available for MS Exchange.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the site guidelines for asking questions in the Help Center. You need to provide information about what you've already tried in your question (code sample).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should make sure you have made the correct request:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[id]/conversations . Please refer to [this link](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs) for details about common queries in graph API. In addition,according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041517/create-groups-calendar-events-fails), please try to access the conversations in Unified (O365) groups.
Hope it helps.